# Working with strange filenames

Tags: shell-script, shell, find

How can the script below be made to always work no matter the filenames returned by find ?

```
#!/bin/sh

cmds_should_always_work() { 
    echo "\n\n*********************************" $1
    stat --printf='%n' -- "$1" || echo STATFAILED
    echo "\n----------------\n"
    lsattr -d -- "$1" || echo LSATTRFAILED
    echo "\n----------------\n"
}; 
for item in $(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1); do cmds_should_always_work "${item}"; done
```

For example files in the find directory that contain a new line break this script.

Further if the find directory is named e.g. $schema, this script returns the parent directory.  How can this be avoided by the script vs. having to supply and escaped path somepath/\$schema to the script?

Comment: Try to use `exec` option of find instead of `for` loop.

Comment: The options are pretty much covered in [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)